# How to add a cron job in lua

Tags: lua

Here I'm trying to add a cron job for a lua project. What I need to do is run specific instructions set daily at a given time. Is there a specific way to schedule a task?  How can I do it.. Is it possible in lua scripts.

Comment: You can invoke any shell command and read its exit code using `os.execute` from your Lua script.  You can invoke any shell command and read its STDOUT using `io.popen` from your Lua script.  Do you have a shell/Bash script (which adds your cron job) already written to start translating it to Lua?